# SHCreateItemFromParsingName and System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, access-violation

I'm taking my first steps in COM but I keep getting System.AccessViolationException which is one of those exceptions which tells you nothing of value. I'm trying to create an IShellItem with SHCreateItemFromParsingName. I copied the definition of the interface from another project so I know there is nothing wrong with it, the problem is most likely in my function definition/call, which I wrote myself for learning purposes.

I want to call the unmanaged function without it returning the IShellItem interface but instead passing a reference of it to the last argument in the call.

The function declaration:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern uint SHCreateItemFromParsingName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPath, IBindCtx pbc, Guid riid, out IShellItem ppv);
```

The function call:

```
IShellItem file;

SHCreateItemFromParsingName(@"C:\file.txt", null, typeof(IShellItem).GUID, out file);
```

I find IDL to be rather cryptic, but my reasoning is:

- HRESULT = uint
- [in] PCWSTR = [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string
- [in, optional] IBindCtx = IBindCtx
- [in] REFIID = Guid
- [out] void = out IShellItem

[SHCreateItemFromParsingName function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the REFIID type parameter. It's not a GUID (a 16 bytes struct), but a GUID reference (*REF*IID), a pointer (so 4 or 8 bytes depending on process bitness).

So you could define the method like this, with a `ref` keyword (so the struct would be passed by reference, as a pointer):

```
internal static extern uint SHCreateItemFromParsingName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPath,
    IBindCtx pbc,
    ref Guid riid,
    out IShellItem ppv);
```

But I recommend this way which is easier to use and avoids creating/copying GUIDs all around (you will call it the same way as you do):

```
internal static extern uint SHCreateItemFromParsingName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPath,
    IBindCtx pbc,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
    out IShellItem ppv);
```

Comment: You seem to know what you're talking about. What book or reference material would you recommend? I didn't get this from the MSDN page I referenced.

Comment: Well, if you know C/C++ then, IDL is very close to it. In fact most .IDL in the Windows SDK have a companion .H file which *is* C/C++ . If you look at REFIID, it's defined as IID* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237816.aspx For .NET p/invoke, Adam Nathan's ".NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide" is probably good to start although some things have evolved quite a lot since the book was written.